# Schwinn Vestige no longer lights up; why not?

Tags: frames

I have the Schwinn Vestige and a very long, bumpy, dirt/gravel driveway.

A few weeks ago, we rode downtown and the frame lit up amazing, as it should.
On the way home, it was not lit up. Hmm.

After a tiny amount of investigation, I found the cap and cover was missing (I mostly blame the driveway).
I ordered a new one (a mere 7 dollars) and installed it.  But alas, the frame still would not light up.

I clipped and stripped the wire from the LED's to the cap/cover thinking they may have been gunk-ified and re-installed the cap/cover.
Nothing. 
I switched the red and black wire within the cap/cover.
Still nothing.

I tested the electrical output from the Shimano DH-3N30 Dynamo hub and all is good.
Still no lights. I pulled the generator/wires out from the frame to inspect for damage and, as expected, there was none.

I am at a total loss.

The local bike shop admitted I knew more about electricity then they did. 
I cannot find any advice or schematic regarding how the lights light up nor can I figure out how to test the lights beyond the hub.

(Note that I have not probed the wires in the frame while spinning the wheel to check for connectivity.)

Comment: Unfortunately, with electrical problems, you're just going to have to systematically go through everything.

Comment: Yes, that part I know. It's the part where I cannot seem to find a schematic about how the bike works.

Comment: Given how rare this bike seems, you're probably going to have to contact Schwinn.

Comment: Did you look in your owner's manual to see if there's a wiring diagram?

Comment: Same thing just happened to my Vestige! Kind of Teed since I don't ride that bicycle rough…
Was thinking of just buying an external light to use the Hub to power it instead. Tough Luck… Fun While it lasted… Almost afraid to ask why there were no lights in the frame?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycling.SE! Thank you for your question Jennifer. We hope you'll stick around, ask more questions, and provide more answers. :) In order to bump your query and get more attention, we encourage you to edit it and provide us with an update.

Comment: The only thing I can see that you didn't report testing was the actual bulbs. Replaceable?

Comment: Daniel,
I ended up going to the local Schwinn dealer and doing a warranty exchange on the lights. Schwinn supplied the whole new setup (as they had initially made it a non-repairable unit) and I installed it.  I had to pull apart the entire headset and clip all the zip ties on the front fork.  The whole process was time consuming, but not challenging.  If the shop had done it, it would have cost me.
The hardest part was treading the new cable through the hole in the frame and cutting it to the correct length.

Comment: They are LED strip lights.

Comment: @jennifer - could you please post what happened as an answer and then accept it by clicking the Tickbox / checkmark?  One more off the "unsolved questions" list.

Comment: Used to be you could take something like this to a radio/TV repair shop, but good luck finding one of those.  You might check locally for a "small appliance repair" outfit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel, I ended up going to the local Schwinn dealer and doing a warranty exchange on the lights. Schwinn supplied the whole new setup (as they had initially made it a non-repairable unit) and I installed it. I had to pull apart the entire headset and clip all the zip ties on the front fork. The whole process was time consuming, but not challenging. If the shop had done it, it would have cost me. The hardest part was treading the new cable through the hole in the frame and cutting it to the correct length

Answer (score 1):

It's about a year later and not sure if you found resolution.  What I found is that the capacitor in the power cube often go bad and there's a guy on ebay that repairs them for $50. http://www.ebay.com/itm/Schwinn-Vestige-led-lights-REPAIR-SERVICE-/281736864772?hash=item4198d36404:g:GugAAOSwPcVViip5

Comment: That's interesting and relevant, but OP says she's already replaced the capacitor.   Plus she replaced the whole lighting array in December 2014.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not sure if "cap" in "cap/cover" in the question means "capacitor" or just "cap", as a synonym of cover (as in "hub cap"). And the information in this answer could still be useful to anyone else having a lighting problem with this bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby totally - that's why I didn't mark it as "not an answer"